# python buffering in sys.stdout

Tags: python, stdout, buffering

Minimal example:

```
def main():
    for i in range(100):
        print("One line every 2s", end = "\n")
        time.sleep(2)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("log.out", 'w') as out, open("log.err", 'w') as err:
        sys.stdout = out
        sys.stderr = err
        main()
```

I want the print statements to be written toe the stdout file after every line. I tried unsuccesfully:

```
python -u thisfile.py
```

In the bashrc (zshrc)

```
PYTHONUNBUFFERED = 1
```

```
open("log.out", 'wb', buffering = 0)
```

Changing the main function is no an option for the real case. A solution where I run the python file with bash and redirect errors and output is ok tough.

I know theres lots of questions like this, but none seem to work for me.

The solution should work ideally for python 3.8 and anything newer.

Comment: So I suppose you can't use `print(..., flush=True)`?

Comment: Setting `sys.stdout` to a different file handle does not mean the new file handle inherits whatever buffering the original standard output used.

Comment: What *can* you change in the script?

Comment: Ideally I don't want to change all print statements scattered across some files, but I guess it wil be my last resort

Comment: Ideally I just want to change the code in the if __name__ == "main" part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `subprocess` module to run the script with the desired options and redirect the output and error streams to the log files:

```
import subprocess

with open("log.out", "w") as out, open("log.err", "w") as err:
    subprocess.run(["python", "-u", "thisfile.py"], stdout=out, stderr=err)
```

This will run the script in unbuffered mode (`-u` option) and redirect the output and error streams to the specified log files.

Comment: It works! Thanks. Any idea why running the file with python -u from the shell does not behave in the same way?

Comment: When you run the script directly from the shell using `python -u thisfile.py`, the standard output and error streams are connected to the terminal, so the data is immediately visible. However, when you redirect the standard output and error streams using the `>` operator or by using the `subprocess` module, the streams are connected to files instead of the terminal, and the data is buffered before it's written to the files. This can result in delayed or buffered output.

Answer (score 0):

you could have a wrapper that automatically flushes stdout after every write. [wrapper taken from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263064/how-can-i-fix-this-valueerror-cant-have-unbuffered-text-i-o-in-python-3)

```py
import time
import sys

class Unbuffered(object):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        self.stream = stream

    def write(self, data):
        self.stream.write(data)
        self.stream.flush()

    def writelines(self, datas):
        self.stream.writelines(datas)
        self.stream.flush()

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.stream, attr)


def main():
    for i in range(100):
        print("One line every 2s", end = "\n")
        time.sleep(2)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("log.out", 'w') as out, open("log.err", 'w') as err:
        sys.stdout = Unbuffered(out)
        sys.stderr = Unbuffered(err)
        main()
```

Comment: I already tries this. I get ValueError: can't have unbuffered text I/O

Comment: @dave okay, i have modified it, now it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use bash you can use:

```
[...]$ python -u main.py > >(tee -a log.out) 2> >(tee -a log.err >&2)
```

main.py

```
import sys
import time

def main():
    for i in range(100):
        print("One line every 2s", end = "\n")
        time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Explanation: [How do I write standard error to a file while using "tee" with a pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/692407/15239951)